# PHP Chat - Storing id in html5?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, chat

I'm trying to create a simple chat using PHP. Everything is working as expected, however came across a potential "exploit". I'm using a AJAX to retrieve all the chat data on scroll (much like Facebook, Twitter, etc). Now comes the problem: I am currently storing the chat id within the dynamically created div itself. For example"

```
<div class="chat" chat_id="4">
    ....
</div>
```

One would be able to change the **chat_id** via the browser which would cause any inputted text to be stored under the incorrect id within the database. What would be the best way to prevent this?

I have currently thought of a method in which all retrieved/initiated chat details (sender, chat id) are stored within the **$_SESSION** variable. This is basically for verification purposes, to ensure that the chat id is valid for the current user.

Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you have a `chat_id` attr?

Comment: They could also just modify their ajax call. Why would you block users from doing this? If they want to write in another chat (that they have access to) why not let them? Why would you not simply set this in js? It still wouldn't be safe though - no client calls/data is. The client can by definition modify everything that they're sending/doing/receiving.

Comment: If you store the chat id in the session, you can check the user when retrieve the messages. If user has no that chat id in the session, don't render anything. As a aside note, I suggest to change `chat_id=""` attribute with `data-chat-id=""` attribute. good practice with `-` and `data-*`

Comment: don't ever trust client sent data

Comment: Using a `$_SESSION` variable is a step to a good direction. Now if you also have the form contain some sort of [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) that will ensure there's no one else hijacking their session.

Comment: Think like a hacker, anybody could craft an XHR to do something the UI doesn't allow. The real security is on the server, if they modify the ID but don't have access to it, a 403 should be thrown. If they do have access, then they did what they wanted to do despite your UI not letting them, but they are allowed to do it

Comment: chat_id may be on client side (as attribute or data-), just check on the server if this user can see the chat or not. Also better practice is to store chat id as variable(parameter) of Model or something for better and cleaner structure.

Comment: @llamerr Don't trust doesn't mean not to store or not to use, just check it again, and again, and...

Comment: @alquist42 yes, exactly - re-check every data from client on server

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of encryption here, here's an example of 128 bit Rijndael encyrption

```
<?php
/*
creating cipher object using Rijndael encyrption algorithm with Cipher-block chaining (CBC) as mode of AES encryption
Here I have chosen 128 bit Rijndael encyrption
*/
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

$key = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF';  // choose a strong iv (32 bytes)

$iv = 'abcdefghijklmnop'; // choose a strong iv (16 bytes)

$plainText = 'This is plain text.'; //here you can use your "id" that you want to encrypt

function encrypt($data, $key, $iv) {
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}

function decrypt($data,$key,$iv) {
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}
echo $ciphertext = encrypt($plainText, $key, $iv);
echo "<br>";
echo $plaintext = decrypt($ciphertext, $key, $iv);
```